# how to loop through columns of a dataframe which have intezers as column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column names as `1,2,3,4..10` . I have sub category of columns as

```
sub_cols = ['1','2','3']
```

I want to loop through these sub_cols

```
for col in sub_cols:
    print('column: '+str(col))
    data[col]
    len(data[col])
```

I get an output

```
column: 1
column: 2
column: 3
```

but data of columns or len of columns is not printed. I don't see any error too. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use ```print()``` with them also.

Comment: print is also not giving any output, is anything with using intezers as column names ?

Comment: Kindly share detailed code of your data-frames. What is **data**?

Comment: `sub_cols = ['1','2','3']` is a list of strings not integers

Answer (score 0):

Your code corrected:

```py
for col in sub_cols:
    print('column: '+str(col))
    print(data[col])
    print(len(data[col])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your fundamental issue if you list of integers is a list of strings.

- following code shows how to loop through columns where name is an integer
- simple list comprehension with `isinstance(c, int)`

```
cols = [i for i in range(5)]+list("abcd")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,5*len(cols)).reshape(5,len(cols)), columns=cols)
df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if isinstance(c, int)]]
```

#### df

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

#### df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if isinstance(c, int)]]

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 1 |